# Selecting max value from group using ArcGIS definition query?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, sql, definition-query

In ArcGIS 10 I am trying to do a Definition Query that will select the records that are the max values from a specific group.

Here is what I have tried in the Query Builder but I am getting an "the SQL statement is invalid." error.

"TL" IN (SELECT max( "TL" ) FROM "Instrument_Locations2_20120227" GROUP BY "Site_ID" )

[image]

Comment: Something is amiss with your quotes... what DBMS is this on?

Comment: Thanks @blah238 the data is contained in a Shapefile which is being queried by a internal query builder within ARCGIS 10.  The double quotes work fine in other queries on same plateform.

Comment: I also believe it is the quotation marks. Can you show a sample of the data?

Comment: Data is actually stored within a file geodatabase.

Comment: data is posted as an image.  I also copied the data to a personal geodatabase.  I tried another version of the statement as brackets are now the default instead of quotes.     [TL] IN (SELECT max( [TL] ) FROM wstest GROUP BY [Site_ID] ).  I tried a few variations of qoutes or brackets around the table name wstest.  Using nothing and also square brackets produced no syntax errors but did not limit the records.

Comment: This was solved by keeping data in personal geodatabase and modifying the statement to:  [TL] <> 0 AND [TL] IN (SELECT MAX( [TL] ) FROM wstest GROUP BY [Site_ID] )

Comment: Please copy the solution you placed in the comment above, into an answer and then accept it.  This will make it easier for someone encountering the same issue, to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by keeping data in personal geodatabase and modifying the statement to: [TL] <> 0 AND [TL] IN (SELECT MAX( [TL] ) FROM wstest GROUP BY [Site_ID] )

Comment: Note that to use the MAX function the layer needs to be in a Personal Geodatabase (not a File Geodatabase!) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000

Answer (score 1):

The only mention of MAX in the [ArcMap SQL Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000.htm) files relates to Subqueries (nested queries).  Not sure if it works for what you're trying, but the syntax used is ALL CAPS.

> This query would return the features with a GDP2006 greater than the GDP2005 of any of the features contained in countries:

```
"GDP2006"(SELECT MAX("GDP2005") FROM countries)
```

> For each record in the table, a subquery may need to parse all the data in its target table. It may be
>   extremely slow to execute on a large dataset.

Comment: Changing the Max to MAX still produced the same error.  Also the statement that I used was given at http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31843 but does not work.

Comment: @user6784 - It says specifically in the ESRI link you provided that shapefiles do not support subqueries.  Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @Baltok - I checked and the data is located within a file geodatabase.

Comment: A file geodatabase has the same restriction as a shapefile in regards to SQL subqueries.  You can export your data to a personal or SDE geodatabase and your query will probably work then.

Comment: Thanks for this @Baltok, I have copied to personal geodatabase and I get no syntax error but the same number of records are being returned.

Comment: @Baltok That is incorrect. ArcGIS does not support subqueries with shapefiles *at all* while it does support them with file or personal geodatabases (see bottom of [this help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002t000000)). The issue is the MAX function as Snorf points out in the accepted answer comment. While nested queries are supported, not all SQL functions are as they depend on the underlying database. Personal uses Access which does, while file is Esri and doesn't. See SQL reference link at the bottom of the above link or Snorf's comment.

Comment: @Chris W- I stand corrected in the blanket statement about shapefile/gdb subquery support.  However, since gdb support for MAX only works in scalar subqueries, you cannot use the same syntax as mdb and sde geodatabases.  I still recommend if you are building semi-complicated SQL queries, you are better off going with mdb or sde geodatabases. YMMV.