# Can ArcGIS 10.1 use SQL on Definition Query to select minimum value?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, definition-query

In ArcGIS 10.1 I am trying to do a Definition Query that will select the records that are the min values from a table.

I try a lot of type of query like and it still not working.
Name table is Polygone_Buffer_Output
Attribute : Air_Mil

```
"Air_Mil" = (SELECT MIN( "Air_Mil" ) FROM "Polygone_Buffer_Output"

[Air_Mil] = (SELECT MIN( [Air_Mil] ) FROM "Polygone_Buffer_Output"

[Air_Mil] = (SELECT MIN( [Air_Mil] ) FROM [Polygone_Buffer_Output]

"Air_Mil" in (SELECT MIN( "Air_Mil" ) FROM "Polygone_Buffer_Output"
```

Comment: A related post may be of help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24163/8104

Comment: What type of table (file, arcsde, dBase, personal) are you using?

Comment: It's with file i'm not able to run my query. But in personal GDB i can execute the query with the advice of CLJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"Air_Mil" in (SELECT MIN( "Air_Mil" ) FROM Polygone_Buffer_Output`

or

`[Air_Mil] in (SELECT MIN( [Air_Mil] ) FROM Polygone_Buffer_Output`

using square brackets or quotes depends on your underlying database implementation.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000

Comment: Thanks, it's run with GDB but when it's only a shapefile a didn't find the way to execute my query

Comment: Did you try both methods?  What message did you get back from ArcGIS when you were trying to query shapefiles?

Comment: It's telling me "There was a problem selecting", "An invalid SQL statement was used." Yes i try both methods and many other. Have you already able to make a query of this kind on a shapefile outside of GDB ?