# How to use MAX SQL statement in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, sql-server

I would like to use a MAX SQL query for a column in a definition query, where there records that are being queried are the MAXIUM from the field `UPDATE_DATE_DATE` while grouping by the field `NUMBERCYLA`.  I am using this in an an SDE enabled geodatabase on SQL server 2008.

Here is what I have so far
`[UPDATE_DATE_DATE] in (SELECT max( [UPDATE_DATE_DATE] ) FROM SO_SC_1 GROUP BY [NUMBERCYLA])`

Comment: What is the type of your database (FGDB, Enterprise,...)? please include it in your question

Comment: Probably better off creating a view, and accessing that.

Comment: If the solution below isn't working, what result are you getting?

Comment: Remove the brackets from field names (Like Tom's suggestion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on SDE, you can achieve what you're asking with:

```
UPDATE_DATE_DATE IN (SELECT MAX(UPDATE_DATE_DATE) FROM SO_SC_1 GROUP BY NUMBERCYLA)
```

As reference for others who may come across this in searching for a file geodatabase solution:

Note that file geodatabases are extremely limited with subqueries. See: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#/SQL_reference_for_query_expressions_used_in_ArcGIS/00s500000033000000/

If you were just trying to retrieve the overall maximum and it's in a file geodatabase or SDE:

```
UPDATE_DATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(UPDATE_DATE_DATE) FROM SO_SC_1)
```

If it's in a personal geodatabase, then you need to move into the 21st century. J/K. see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26750/10919

If you're interested in getting the maxima grouped by some other field and your feature class is in an FGDB, then you're out of luck. You will need to implement a work-around in which you identify, select, and export the features to a new feature class.