# Find records with highest value based on unique ID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, table, unique-id

I'm trying to find a way to return all records that have the highest value in a field for each set of unique IDs. The attached table shows what I'm trying to achieve. The highlighted records would be the ones I want to have selected so I can export them to a new table.

For each set of unique IDs (Int_ID) I want to select those that have the highest value in (MPO_Lanes). I need to keep all the attributes, so Case items in Summary Statistics does not appear to work.

If your curious why I want to do this...for each Street Intersection (Int_ID), I want to identify which Street Legs (ExtID) have the most lanes (MPO_Lanes) and therefore identifying which Street Legs would be considered the "Major" street at that intersection.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1, advanced.

[image]

Comment: What sort of database/feature source are your features in? If you're using personal (not file) geodatabase or SDE you can use the MAX operator https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/arcgis-10-definition-query-to-select-the-max-value-from-a-group

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't think the Max operator will work because I need the max determined within the groups of identical INT_IDs. I posted a better example of the table. Note MPO_Lanes = 3 is selected for INT_ID 2681 but MPO_Lanes = 2 is selected for INT_ID 2934.

Comment: BTW, the data is in a file GDB, but could be moved to SDE or personal GDB.

Comment: You could create a summary table with Summary Statistics http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000 with a *case field* of Int_ID and *summary field* of MPO_Lanes with the MAXIMUM statistics type then join by Int_ID and select where SumTable.MPO_Lanes_Maximum = MPO_Lanes (field names are assumed but after the join you should see fairly clearly in the select by attributes dialog).

Comment: Looks like a task for Summary Statistics

Comment: Thank you Michael and jbalk. Both suggestions should work.

Comment: You're welcome, but the way to say thank you on this site is to either upvote or accept the answer if you have found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following arcpy script will accomplish what you want.  This can be added to a script tool and has 5 parameters:

```
import arcpy

infc = arcpy.GetParameter(0) # Input feature class
infield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  # Group By Field
stcountfield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)  # Street Count Field
streetname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)  # Street Name or ID field
primaryst = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)  #  New field to hold Primary Street name or id

def maxkey(dict):
    keylist = []
    for key in dict.iterkeys():
        keylist.append(key)
    return max(keylist)

# Create set from group-by field values
fieldvals = []      
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc,[infield]) as scur:
    for row in scur:
        fieldvals.append(row[0])
del scur
fieldset = []
for field in set(fieldvals):
    fieldset.append(field)

# Create dictionary of max street count = street name, update records with primary street per group-by value

for val in fieldset:
    maxvaluedict = {}
    primstdict = {}
    expression = infield+"="+str(val)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(infc,"NEW_SELECTION",expression)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc,[infield,stcountfield,streetname]) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            if row[1] not in maxvaluedict:
                maxvaluedict[row[1]] = [row[0]]
            elif row[0] not in maxvaluedict[row[1]]:
                maxvaluedict[row[1]].append(row[0])
            if row[1] not in primstdict:
                primstdict[row[1]] = [row[2]]
            elif row[2] not in primstdict[row[1]]:
                primstdict[row[1]].append(row[2])
    del cur

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc,[infield,primaryst]) as ucur:
        for row in ucur:
            row[0] = val
            elist = []
            for e in primstdict[maxkey(maxvaluedict)]:
                elist.append(str(e))
            row[1] = ','.join(elist)
            ucur.updateRow(row)
    del ucur
```

For an example, I've run this on my roads table and set

infield = "LOC"

stcountfield = "PAR_NUM"

streetname = "FEAT_NAME"

primaryst = "PrimaryStreet"

As you can see, PrimaryStreet was populated with the street name of the largest PAR_NUM, grouped by LOC.

[image]